# MonkeyTalk-While recording not recognizing the recorded script in MonkeyTalk,is any problems with me?

Tags: eclipse, recording, monkeytalk

We tried to Implement two  types of scenarios on Monkey Talk

One is recording through Source Code and Converting Eclipse Project to Aspect J project-Its working fine.

Second scenario we tried to use the .APK file for same project we are unable to record the apk formatted set up

Clarifications needed for Below points:

1. Can we record .APK file setups in Monkey talk or not
2. As per My Observation from Web  we can  use .APK file but I am
   Unable to Find out the Solution for my Problem.

Looking forward to assist with you if you have any concerns & Waiting or your Informative reply..

Best Regards,

Uday Reddy.S

Answer (score 0):

I was able to record using .apk when the device was connected by the option Android Device(USB). You will have to wait for 10-15 secs for the record button to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to make your app source code compatible with Monkeytalk by below steps and after than you can automate it 
steps are :

1)Download MonkeyTalk for gorilla logic website and unzip it.

2)Open Eclipse and convert your project on "Aspectj" (need a plugin aspectj - for eclipse)- Once it get downloaded right click on your app,configure,Convert to aspectj.

3)Then under your project folder structure search for "libs" folder if it's exist then ok else create it.

4)Once it get done go to monkeytalk,agents,android,Monkeytalkjar file. Copy it and paste it under libs folder.

5)Once it done click on "jar" file and right click on it,Aspectjtools,Add to aspectpath.

6)Then go to Androidmanifest.xml file where we have to add some permissions;

```
<Uses-permissions android:name="android.Permission.INTERNET/>
<Uses-permissions android:name="android.Permission.Get_TASKS/>
```

and save it.

7)Go to project click on it,Right click,properties,JavaBuild Path,Check the "Aspectj Runtime Library,Ok.

8)Run your application as a Android application.

9) Open monkey talk.

10) Create new project,Create new script.

11)Then set the android sdk path under prefences; MonkeyTalk,MonketTalkPrefences,Android SDK path,ok.

12) Connect to emulator on monkeytalk.

Now you will be able to record and play in MonkeyTalk.

Some start up code for your reference eg; if we have two textfield username and password and one button submit.

```
app.input("username").entertext("aakash");
app.input("password").entertext("jaiswal");
app.button("submit").tap();
```